# How to combine these 2 commands into single line command

Tags: bash, csh

I have 2 useful bash command below, but i want to combine it together.
Is it possible to do ?

```
find "$1" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sha1sum -b
find "$1" -type f ! -iname '*thumbs.db*' -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c "%y %s %n"
```

Comment: What should the "combined" command do?

Comment: .. and what is wrong in using it this way?

Comment: I want to get "FileName", "Size(byte)", "Sha1", "LastModified", I think if i can combine them, the result will looks better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **write it in one line**, you can just use "&" to combine the commands. Maybe this is what you meant:

```
find "$1" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sha1sum -b & find "$1" -type f ! -iname '*thumbs.db*' -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c "%y %s %n"
```

Comment: Thank you, But i meant can we actually combine it. I don't want to get the file name 2 times.